# C++/QT Safely terminate a blocking thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, boost

I am creating an application, that communicates with a server using an API's functions, from an existing code base written in C++/Qt 5.6 and Boost. The code is written in a way such that, any communication with the server is done by the API's functions that runs in a worker object. The worker object runs in a `QThread()`, and is moved using `moveToThread`.

My problem is that, I need to be able to stop the thread immediately and disconnect in the situation where the network connection drops. However, the thread blocks when it sends data to the server. If I try to stop the thread through `quit() or wait()`, the request still goes through to the server which is undesirable. The API doesn't offer any method to cancel any ongoing requests either.

My current solution is terminating the thread, and destroying the worker object it owns when the network connection drops. I then create a new QThread and new worker object when connecting to the server.

I know that `terminate()` or any kind of immediate termination of a thread should be avoided like the plague but it seems to work I think.

The worker object that runs in the QThread uses `std::shared_ptr` for it's members through `std::make_shared`.

Are there still chances of memory leaks/corruption?

Apart from this, because I create my QThread in a method, I receive a warning from QT:

`QObject: cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread`

Despite this warning, my code still runs but I have doubts. Is it safe to ignore this warning? What are the risks/consequences of ignoring this?

Is it safer to litter the server connecting code with QT's interruption checking points/rewrite it in boost using `boost::interruption_point` instead of calling terminate? i.e

```
sendData();
if (QThread::currentThread()->isInterruptionRequested())
{
 return;
}
sendData();
if (QThread::currentThread()->isInterruptionRequested())
{
 return;
}
...
```

Advice much appreciated thanks.

Comment: The reason unilateral termination of a thread should be avoided like the plague is that when the thread terminates, its call stack will be abandoned rather than unwound, which means none of the destructors for its stack objects will execute, which means any resources held by the thread will never be released.  In particular things like mutexes can be left locked indefinitely, causing your program to deadlock.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner So even `shared_ptr<>`'s won't have their memory released right in that situation?

Comment: `shared_ptrs<>` typically work by reference-counting -- i.e. the destructor of the `shared_ptr<>` decrements a counter, and if that counter reaches zero, the `shared_ptr<>` destructor will then call delete on the object it references.  Needless to say, if the `shared_ptr<>`'s destructor never executes, that won't happen, and your object will be left alive forever because its reference-count will never reach zero.